# Ceres Solver: Bundle adjustment

Tags: camera-calibration, ceres-solver

I have a calibrated camera. I took video with it in circular motion.
[image]

I want to find the camera extrinsic for each frame with bundle adjustment.

The matching use cv::findHomography(RANSAC) to remove the outliers. And the result is almost perfect.

[image]

After finding the matching points, I use google's ceres solver to do bundle adjustment.

if there are only two frames, the result is good. And I've reproject the point cloud. They looks correct.

However, I failed to do BA on multiple frames. I've tried several strategies:
(I must keep scaling factor constant)

1. Initialize all point at (0, 0, 100) in world coordinate. Initialize all camera in (0, 0, 0) with zero rotation. Fix the first view extrinsic. Start doing BA..
2. BA several times. First iteration for frame 1 and frame 2. second iteration for frame 2 and 3. Each iteration I put new observed point on (0, 0, 100) in camera space.(Reprojection function can't handle points behind the camera)

The first approach is bad. 
The second one is better. But it is not allowed to have constant scaling factor..

Comment: Does the OpenMVG pipeline (http://openmvg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/software/SfM/SfM/) give any decent results on your data set? Maybe try to estimate the focal length, principal point and distortion parameters of your camera yourself by camera calibration and use them as priors to reduce the number of BA parameters? Maybe include rough estimates of the camera poses as well? I remember that if you use Snavely's reprojection error (http://ceres-solver.org/nnls_tutorial.html#bundle-adjustment) the z-axis is different from the default OpenCV one in case you are mixing Ceres Solver and OpenCV.

Comment: I've solve the problem myself. The initial guess is very important. I at least need to calculate rotation of each view. so the first approach is bad.
Ceres solver let us write our own reprojection function. there's no pain on mixing two libraries